# Random 401, 403 with jfrog artifactory (DENIED LOGIN)

Tags: artifactory

I am running jfrog 7.12.6 as a Docker container in a EC2 instance under a ELB and Cloudfront.

Some random 401 and 403 error codes when trying to get resources from artifactory are happening and I couldn't correlate with any other event.

Looking at the log data, i can see that Artifactory is able to identify the user and denies the download for two files and the third one works, everything in the same second.

If we run the build again everything works fine.

I dont know how to reproduce it, it is random.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
artifactory-access.log:
2021-01-20T23:09:50.436Z [xxxxxx1] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : myuser / 100.00.00.000.
2021-01-20T23:09:50.444Z [xxxxxx2] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : myuser / 100.00.00.000.
2021-01-20T23:09:50.445Z [xxxxxx3] [ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] serve-static-1.13.8.tgz  for client : user / 100.00.00.000.

artifactory-request.log:

2021-01-20T23:09:50.436Z|xxxxxx1|100.000.000|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/npm/npm/aws-sdk/-/aws-sdk-2.824.0.tgz|403|-1|0|1|Amazon CloudFront
2021-01-20T23:09:50.444Z|xxxxxx2|100.000.000|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/npm/npm/chai-json-schema-1.4.6.tgz|403|-1|0|1|Amazon CloudFront
2021-01-20T23:09:50.446Z|xxxxxx3|100.000.000|myuser|GET|/api/npm/npm/serve-static-1.13.8.tgz|200|-1|3143|14|Amazon CloudFront
```